# How bind some nodes in spritekit and move them in a bunch along one trajectory?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I create game with spriteKit in Xcode. I need to create carousel and move 4 nodes around one pillar. 
[carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iP1w.png)

How can I move some bind nodes? It`s necessary to change zPosition when node approaches the pillar and when node comes out from behind the pillar. How it can be implemented?

Comment: You'll need to explain better; perhaps with some diagrams as it's not clear what visual effect you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

To group your nodes together, just create a new `SKNode`, add it to the scene, and anything that needs to be grouped to this, just call `move(toParent:)` on the nodes that need to be moved.

```
let groupedNode = SKNode()
self.addChild(groupedNode)

node1.move(toParent:groupedNode)
```

As for zPosition, it is relative to the parent,  so if your pillar is at 2, and your group is at 1, to make your individual nodes above the pillar, you need to make the node 2.  This will make the node zPosition really 3 (node + group) placing it above the pillar.